# Laravel Maatwebsite/Excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel). And I need to export a view file to xls format using the codes below.

#### Controller File:

```
public function excel(){
   return Excel::download(new Export($id), 'test.xls');
}
```

#### Export File

```
public function __construct($id){
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function view(): View {
    $obj = Object::find($this->id);

    return view('project.view', [
        'var' => $obj,
    ]);
}
```

The exported file is looking a bit good.

But my concern is, how to make the cells , auto width, depending on the content, and the styles, border are gone.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to make the cells auto width, how to style cells or how to add borders to cells?

Comment: @Loek all of those you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Way.

```
use Excel;
$data=array();
Excel::create('Sheet Name', function($excel) use($data) {

     $excel->sheet('Sheet', function($sheet) use($data){
      $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
         $sheet->loadView('view',compact('data'));

    });

  })->export('xls');
```

Comment: I'm using v3.0

I've found some tutorials using "Excel::create", but unfortunately it returns an error saying that ::create is not found, something like that.

Comment: "Excel::create" isnt worked for latest version. If you want to use the create method, you should downgrade Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel version to 2.+.